# Auto filtering a table with a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have three ComboBoxes that are populated with numbers and am trying to filter a table when the following macro is called. The problem is on various tests it filters correctly then returns a blank table with all blank rows. The ComboBoxes are loaded correctly, there are rows in the table that match the criteria in the test.

Sub AutoFilter()

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value
If Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=number1
 If Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=number2
If Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=number3
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is there at least one row in the table that matches all three criteria? The `.AutoFilter` you've used is an AND condition, not an OR.

Comment: There is Jeeped, I made sure of it in that theres rows in the table such that in col 1 number 1 exists in col2 number 2 exists and in col 3 number3 exists

Comment: Does the data type in the combobox match the data type in the table? If you have numbers in your table your combo box is probably text and this might not filter correctly

Comment: Clint: They're both text I double checked